# retrieve IMEI for android using actionscript3

Tags: android, actionscript

I m developing an app that pulls android device IMEI and matches it against the database
Is there a way to retrieve android device IMEI using actions script?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, sadly there is no interface to the native API yet, even the Android Team agrees that it should be there. You should rather use Math.random() and store it locally as it provides more or less the same functionality. Have a read here:
http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2011/03/unique-device-identifiers-on-air-mobile.html

Answer (score 0):

They could have used the IMEI on Android. Looks like someone made an ANE.

http://blog.snowflax.com/native-imei-action-script-extension-for-android/